# Font-awesome disturbing commands of moderncv

Tags: fonts, moderncv, fontawesome

The usage of `\moderncvicons{awesome}` lowers the item symboles (blue circle) of `\cvlistdoubleitem` and `\cvlistitem`. How can they be raised to normal level again?

MWE:

```
% compile with LuaLaTeX

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 
\moderncvstyle{classic} 
\moderncvcolor{blue} 

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}                     
\moderncvicons{awesome}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}

\begin{document}

\cvlistdoubleitem{Ultimate Frisbee}{Climbing}
\cvlistitem{Travelling in Europe, Asia and North America}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Note that this doesn't happen if you compile with pdflatex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Update (`moderncv` v2.0)

`moderncv` v2.0 uses latest version of `fontawesome`, where the symbol `\faCircleBlank` has been replaced by `\faCircleO`, so

```
\renewcommand*{\labelitemi}{\strut\textcolor{color1}{\raisebox{1pt}{\tiny\faCircleBlank}}}
```

has to be replaced with

```
\renewcommand*{\labelitemi}{\strut\textcolor{color1}{\raisebox{1pt}{\tiny\faCircleO}}}
```

---

### Original answer (works with older versions of `moderncv`)

Add this line to your preamble

```
\renewcommand*{\labelitemi}{\strut\textcolor{color1}{\raisebox{1pt}{\tiny\faCircleBlank}}}
```

Complete MWE

```
% compile with LuaLaTeX

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\moderncvicons{awesome}

\renewcommand*{\labelitemi}{\strut\textcolor{color1}{\raisebox{1pt}{\tiny\faCircleBlank}}}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}

\begin{document}

\cvlistdoubleitem{Ultimate Frisbee}{Climbing}
\cvlistitem{Travelling in Europe, Asia and North America}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

P.S. As I said in my comment, this is not needed if you compile the document with `pdflatex`, but just because in this case `moderncv` turns the font to "marvosym"...

---

### EDIT

To prevent errors when running it with `pdflatex` it is better to encase

```
\renewcommand*{\labelitemi}{\strut\textcolor{color1}{\raisebox{1pt}{\tiny\faCircleBlank}}}
```

in a `\ifxetexorluatex`...`\fi` statement:

```
\ifxetexorluatex
\renewcommand*{\labelitemi}{\strut\textcolor{color1}{\raisebox{1pt}{\tiny\faCircleBlank}}}
\fi
```

so that the previous MWE becomes:

```
% compile with LuaLaTeX

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\moderncvicons{awesome}

\ifxetexorluatex
\renewcommand*{\labelitemi}{\strut\textcolor{color1}{\raisebox{1pt}{\tiny\faCircleBlank}}}
\fi

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}

\begin{document}

\cvlistdoubleitem{Ultimate Frisbee}{Climbing}
\cvlistitem{Travelling in Europe, Asia and North America}

\end{document}
```